# Can I write a macro that detects if the text mode is currently in '\uppercase{xxxx}'

Tags: macros

My aim is to define a macro that can react to the text currently being in `\uppercase` mode.
So for example if my macro is called `\mymacro` we should be able to print 'UPPER' or 'normal'.

In the document we can then type:

`Hello\mymacro` which would result in: `Hellonormal`

or `\uppercase{Hello\mymacro}` which would result in: `HELLOUPPER`

I've tried macros like: `\curr@fontshape` of `\f@size` etc. But none of them seem to be able to distinguish between normal or uppercase printed text

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: why the minus one vote? is there something wrong?

Comment: unlike caps and small caps, uppercase is not achieved via a font change but by modifying the input string, changing `a` to `A` so you will not see any change in the font settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never use `\uppercase` in latex (it will break input encoding support amongst other problems). The standard `\MakeUppercase` expands its argument, so expands your macro before uppercasing, and allows `\CaseSwitch` for this use case, so long as you have a new enough LaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mymacro{}{%
This is in \CaseSwitch
 {normal}
 {upper}
 {lower}
 {titlecase}%hmm
}

\begin{document}


1 \mymacro

2 \MakeLowercase{\mymacro}

3 \MakeUppercase{\mymacro}

4 \MakeTitlecase{\mymacro}

\end{document}
```

This allows full control over what happens when uppercase is detected, but perhaps  you just need the simple

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mymacro{}{my macro text}

\begin{document}


1 \mymacro

2 \MakeLowercase{\mymacro}

3 \MakeUppercase{\mymacro}

4 \MakeTitlecase{\mymacro}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Why `\MakeTitlecase{\CaseSwitch{normal}{UPPER}{lower}{Title}}` produces 'Lower' not  'Title'?

Comment: @Stephen see the extensive documentation of that in the inline comment

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1316

Comment: It seems that this is a bug?

Comment: @Stephen possibly or possibly not, to be decided, this version of title case lowercases all but the first word  so arguably lowercase is the right thing here.